# How do I enable the Views Contact Form module?

Tags: views, 8

I cannot install the [Views Contact Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contact_form) module because it depends from the Email module, which is said to be missing, in the module page. The Email module is not a Drupal 8 core module.

How do I install that module?

Comment: use drush 8 to enable this module.

Comment: It would not work, since the module declares a wrong dependency.

Comment: Plus, it is not even updated to work with the official releases of Drupal 8; if Drush could install it, it would install an useless module.

Answer (score 2):

The [Views Contact Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contact_form) module doesn't actually works for Drupal 8, since it puts its class files in [module directory]/lib/Drupal/views_contact_form (PSR0), when Drupal 8 now requires them to be in [module directory]/src (PSR4), inside the module directory. Looking at the code, I notice the module has not been updated to work with the official releases of Drupal 8.0, nor 8.1.

For this reason, not even removing the dependency on the *Email Field* module from 
the [views_contact_form.info.yml](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_contact_form/tree/views_contact_form.info.yml?h=8.x-1.x) file would work. Otherwise, I would have suggested to change the views_contact_form.info.yml file as follows.

```
name: Views Contact Form
description: Views Contact Form
core: 8.x
type: module
dependencies:
 - views
```

To add more details about the dependecies, the *Views Contact Form* module declares its dependency from the [Email Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module, which is only for Drupal 7. In the project page of the latter module, it's clearly stated:

> The basic email field type is in core now: [#1668332: Add an E-mail field type into core](https://www.drupal.org/node/1668332), making this contrib module obsolete. Specific formatters (like the contact form) can live in separate contrib modules.

It seems the *Views Contact Form* module implements one of those formatters, so it would just require the email field already present in core. Unfortunately, the module has not been updated to work with the latest releases of Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like that module needs an update. The email field is a field type plugin, not a module in latest 8.1.x branch. I think the dependency could be safely removed from the module, but I have not tested myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the module doesn't work with the official releases of Drupal 8. See my answer for the details. +1 for pointing out that the email field is already in core, for Drupal 8.